# List comprehension - converting strings in one list, to integers in another

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Basically, I have a string given as follows: "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90".

I need to convert that in such a fashion that I will be able to sum each of the individual numbers making up the numbers above, i.e. 56 would become 5 + 6 would become 11.

So far I have taken the following approach:

```
l = string.split()

new_l = []

# the below creates a list as follows: [['56'],['65'], ['74'] etc.]
for x in l:
    new_l += [x.split()]

# while this list comprehension simply splits the list up: [['5','6'], etc.]
list_of_lists = [list(y) for x in new_l for y in x]

# now, if I could convert the numbers in those inner lists into integers, 
# I'd be getting where I need to

# but for some reason, this list comprehension does not return what I need
l_o_l = [[int(x)] for x in y for y in list_of_lists]
```

The last list comprehension simply returns a number of 9s and 0s and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Forgive my ignorance on this one, I've read a couple of explanations but they don't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What should the final result look like based on the sample input you specified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly:

```
>>> example = "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90"
>>> example.split()
['56', '65', '74', '100', '99', '68', '86', '180', '90']
```

So all you really need is:

```
>>> [sum(map(int,s)) for s in example.split()]
[11, 11, 11, 1, 18, 14, 14, 9, 9]
>>>
```

They key here is that strings are *already iterable*. No need to convert them to lists.

Also, note that your last comprehension has the for-expressions backwards and should throw an error. Instead, this is probably what you meant:

```
>>> [[int(x)] for y in list_of_lists for x in y]
[[5], [6], [6], [5], [7], [4], [1], [0], [0], [9], [9], [6], [8], [8], [6], [1], [8], [0], [9], [0]]
```

I'm not sure how you are getting 9's and 0's.

What you probably wanted was something like:

```
>>> l_o_l = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in list_of_lists]
>>> l_o_l
[[5, 6], [6, 5], [7, 4], [1, 0, 0], [9, 9], [6, 8], [8, 6], [1, 8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

And then, finally, use the following:

```
>>> [sum(l) for l in l_o_l]
[11, 11, 11, 1, 18, 14, 14, 9, 9]
>>>
```

But again, this approach is over-engineered because *strings are already iterable*.

Comment: Wow, I'm a huge idiot. That's amazing, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ThatCob You are welcome. Remember, in Python, iterators are everywhere. It is a core feature of the language. If you think this answers the question, you can accept by using the checkmark next to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows :

```
list = s.split() # Where s is your original string
[sum(int(i) for i in num) for num in list]
```

Output :

```
[11, 11, 11, 1, 18, 14, 14, 9, 9]
```

Comment: For the `sum` part, you don't need the comprehension, you can use an expression instead: `sum(int(i) for i in num)`. Also, don't use `list` as a *list* name because it shadows the built-in *list*.

Comment: @idjaw : Thanks for your feedback ! I updated my answer